# HTTP headers not working in $.AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, get

No matter which method I try for setting headers in AJAX call and no matter which header I set, every-time, if there is a header, my AJAX call is aborted, and call doesn't go through, and since I need to set Authorization header, if no header is there, call returns 401.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

var authorizationToken=1;
$.ajax
({
type: "GET",
url: "http://<someURL>?$format=json",
beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
            },
success: function (){
  alert('Thanks for your comment!');
},
error: function (a,b,c,d){
  alert('Try again please');
}
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

If  there is no header present, call is not aborted and 401 is returned. Can you please tell me what is wrong in AJAX call? Since this works in rest client with same server, i don't think its a server issue.

Comment: Is the request getting through to the server?  can you see it with something like Fiddler?  (bear in mind you can't see localhost requests with fiddler, so your client and server will need to be running on 2 different hosts).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990010/authorization-header-appended-only-once-in-ajax-cors-request

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console, does it show any error messages? Look at the network tab, is the request being sent the one you expect? I'm betting on a same origin policy violation at the moment.

Comment: In dev console, no request is shown, In debug mode, it goes to error with arguments: status:0, statusText:"error"
2nd argument: "error"
3rd argument: ""

No request is going in networks tab, but it goes when there is no header at all.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean to set the `Authorization` header instead of `Authority`?

Comment: Yes, it was Authorization as i stated earlier, here its Authority just to show code and problem is even if i pass Authority, same issue happens, no call goes.